# A question on Parallel transport on a symplectic space

Tags: differential-geometry, symplectic-geometry

First of all, I have a background in physics and not mathematics so the statement of the problem will not be as rigorous as mathematicians like, sorry about that. In fact, I would appreciate if somebody could help me to formalize the problem.

**Statement:** Let $(q,p)$ be a set of local coordinates in 2-dimensional symplectic space. Let $\lambda=(\lambda_{1},\lambda_{2},...,\lambda_{n})$ be a set of local coordinates of certain open set of a differentiable manifold $\mathcal{M}$. For some $\lambda_{0}$ we define two differentiable functions $Q_{0}=Q_{0}(q,p,\lambda_{0})$ and $P_{0}=P_{0}(q,p,\lambda_{0})$ such that $dq\wedge dp=dQ_{0}\wedge dP_{0}$.

For the other $\lambda$ we also want functions $(Q_{\lambda},P_{\lambda})$ such that $dq\wedge dp=dQ_{\lambda}\wedge dP_{\lambda}$. However, we don't want $(Q_{\lambda},P_{\lambda})$ to depend only on a given value of $\lambda$ but they should depend also on the path taken from $\lambda_{0}$ to $\lambda$. This is, we want a notion of parallel transport.

Assume we have an operator $G=\left\{ \cdot,g\right\} =\partial_{q}g\partial_{p}-\partial_{p}g\partial_{q}$, where $g=g_{i}d\lambda_{i}$ and $g_{i}=g_{i}(q,p,\lambda_{i})$ and the bracket is the Poisson bracket. For $\lambda$ very close to $\lambda_{0}$ we define parallel transport as $$Q_{\lambda} =Q_{0}+G[Q_{0}]=Q_{0}+\left\{ Q_{0},g\right\},$$
$$P_{\lambda} =P_{0}+G[P_{0}]=P_{0}+\left\{ P_{0},g\right\},$$

I guess $G$ (or maybe $g$?) is some form of a connection 1-form. I'm interested in the curvature 2-form of $G$. In particular, can the components of the of the curvature can be expressed using the Poisson bracket as $F_{ij}=\left\{ \cdot,f_{ij}\right\}$ ?.